# remove header div from a specific pages with dom

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to remove a section of the header with DOM for an A/B test.
I need to do it just in two pages, but the problem is that I have the same classes in all the pages with the header and I don't want to remove it from all pages.

The html structure is like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark fiex-top">
<div class="header-logo">
<div class="progress-indicator">
</nav>
<section class="main-page-container">
<div class="container about-page">
```

I need to remove "progress-indicator"

I tried adding this code

```
 const new1 = document.querySelector(".main-page-container");
    if (new1.classList.contains('about-page')) {
      document.querySelector(".progress-indicator").remove();
    }
```

And this one

```
   const removeheader = querySelector(".container.about-page");
if (removeheader.length > 1) {
document.querySelector(".progress-indicator").remove();
}
```

It was the idea I had, because inside  I have a div with a different class in each page, but it didn't give me results, I don't know if it's possible to modify it like this

Comment: Welcome to the community Gisselle. can you please let us know where did you place that script?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
 const removeheader1 = document.querySelector(".container.about-page");
        if (removeheader1.classList.contains('about-page')) {
          document.querySelector(".progress-indicator").remove();
        }
```

It seems that the problem was in the way I added the classes